# Can Project Navigator show target membership in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, project-navigator

In older versions of Xcode, if I remember correctly you could show extra columns in the Project Navigator (kind of like the version control icons) to show things like current target membership, etc.  I can't find that in Xcode 4.5.  Anyone know how to get at that now?  I just want to see the list of checkboxes showing which files are part of the target.

### Note

Yes, I know you can click the target, navigate to the 'Build Phases', then check the relevant sections there to see them all at once, but there you lose the context of your group hierarchies.

You used to be able to just click the checkboxes right down the side of Project Navigator (or whatever it used to be called.)

I googled around and saw someone else said it was removed from Xcode 4.x so maybe that's why I can't find it.  That's crazy if that's the case though, but Apple has done stranger things.

Answer (score 0):

It's there in the `Utilities > File inspector` tab. You can show/hide it using `Option + Command + 0` or navigating to `View > Utilities > Show Utilitites`.

Comment: No, that's for a specific file.  The old Xcode used to allow you to add another column of checkboxes to the Project Navigator (kind of like the version control icons) so you could see all of your files at once.  I also just read on another forum that it was removed.  I'll wait a little to see if that person was wrong and someone else knows where this is.  Otherwise I guess this is a dead question.

Comment: No.  That shows all targets a file can belong to.  I'm looking for the opposite... all files that belong to the target.  Again, this was in the Project Navigator beside all of your files (well, the 'm', 'mm', 'c', 'cpp' files anyway.)  Again, you could look at all the files in the group and see which had checkboxes next to them so you could, at a glance, see which files were in that target all at once.